# TypeScript inheritance - how to add some fields to already existing property

Tags: typescript

I write Angular app with TypeScript and now I'm stuck trying to implement class hierarchy to manage JSON objects I get from backend.

Let's say I get `Car` object with several elements. JSON object looks like

```
{
    "id": 19,
    "title": "Big Car",
    "status": "running",
    "elements": [{
        "id": 697,
        "type": "steering wheel",
        "options": {
            "carPart": "steering",
            "airbag": true
        }
    }, {
        "id": 700,
        "type": "wheel",
        "options": {
            "carPart": "wheels",
            "radius": 16,
            "tyreType": "winter",
            "position": "front left"
        }
    }]
}
```

Previously I didn't have `element.options.carPart` property, so my classes were like

```
export class Car{
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public title: string,
    public stauts: string,
    public elements: CarElement[]
  ) {}
}

export class CarElement {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: string
  ) {}
}

export class SteeringWheel extends CarElement {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: string,
    public options: { airbag: boolean }
  ) {
    super(id, type);
  }
}

export class Wheel extends CarElement {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: string,
    public options: { radius: number, tyreType: string, position: string }
  ) {
    super(id, type);
  }
}
```

Now I need to have `element.options.carPart` in `CarElement` class, and access it as `CarElement` property.

But I can't just change CarElement to

```
export class CarElement {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: string,
    public options: { carPart: string }
  ) {}
}
```

Of course, I get `error TS2415: Class 'Wheel' incorrectly extends base class 'carElement'. Types of property 'options' are incompatible.`

So, my question is - is there any option to keep JSON structure intact, keep object structure, and somehow extend already existing class property?

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
export class CarElement {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: string,
    public options: CarElementOptions
  ) {}
}

export class CarElementOptions {
    constructor(public carPart: string) {}
}


export class SteeringWheel extends CarElement {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: string,
    public options: SteeringWheelOptions
  ) {
    super(id, type);
  }
}

export class SteeringWheelOptions extends CarElementOptions{
    constructor(public carPart: string, public airbag: boolean){
       super(carPart);
    }
}

export class Wheel extends CarElement {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public type: string,
    public options: WheelOptions
  ) {
    super(id, type);
  }
}

export class WheelOptions extends CarElementOptions{
    constructor(
       public carPart: string, 
       public radius: number,
       public typeType: string,
       public position: string
    ){
       super(carPart);
    }
}
```